# output is printing before taking input from command prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello everyone i'am new to javascript.
in these code obj print first and then command prompt taking input
i use async and await please correct the code.

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout
});
async function create() {
 let obj = {fname:"",lname:"",email_adds:"",phone_number:""}
 readline.question("Enter First name",function(name) {
    readline.question("Enter Last name",function(lname){
        readline.question("Enter Email address ",function(em){
            readline.question("Enter Phone number ",function(ph){
                obj.fname = name
                obj.lname = lname
                obj.email_adds = em
                obj.phone_number = ph
                
         readline.close();
            });
        });
    });
 });
 function print(){
     console.log(obj)
 }
 await print()
}
create()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert this into `Promise`.

So `console.log` will wait until `Promise` resolves.

The `Promise` object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

If the asynchronous operation is successful, the expected result is returned by calling the `resolve` function. Likewise, if some unexpected error occurred during the execution of the asynchronous operation, the result is returned by the `reject` function.

When either `resolve` or `reject` has been called, the promise has been settled.

The `then` callback is triggered when the promise is resolved. It’s also possible to chain `then` method callbacks. The `catch` callback is executed when the promise is rejected.

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout
});
function create() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let obj = {
            fname: "",
            lname: "",
            email_adds: "",
            phone_number: ""
        }
        readline.question("Enter First name", function(name) {
            readline.question("Enter Last name", function(lname) {
                readline.question("Enter Email address ", function(em) {
                    readline.question("Enter Phone number ", function(ph) {
                        obj.fname = name
                        obj.lname = lname
                        obj.email_adds = em
                        obj.phone_number = ph
                        readline.close();
                        resolve(obj);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        
    })
}
create().then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
})
```